# Boost regex_search infinite loop

Tags: c++, regex, boost, infinite-loop

I'm having trouble linking Boost Regex to my program. And by that, I mean Code::Blocks has been giving me some trouble.

Here is the code for the program that I got from another forum, with a couple extra print statements.

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
   std::string   str = "The boost library has a great opportunity for the regex";
   std::cout << "Here 1" << std::endl;
   boost::regex  rex("\\b(?:\\w+?)((\\w)\\2)(?:\\w+?)\\b");
   std::cout << "Here 2" << std::endl;
   boost::smatch res;
   std::cout << "Here 3" << std::endl;

   std::string::const_iterator begin = str.begin();
   std::cout << "Here 4" << std::endl;
   std::string::const_iterator end   = str.end();

   while (boost::regex_search(begin, end, res, rex))
   {
      std::cout << "Here 5" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "Word, we've searched, is \"" << res[0] << "\".  It has two \""
                << res[2]
                << "\" inside itself."
                << std::endl;

      begin = res[1].second;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

If I press f9 in Code::Blocks, the program runs fine, however, when I try running from outside Code::Blocks:

```
cd ~/letter_finder/bin/Release
./letter_finder
```

I get the following output:

```
dhcp-1218-32-207-253:Release admin$ ./ubuntu
Here 1
Here 2
Here 3
Here 4
```

and I need to keyboard interrupt to exit. I know the problem is with linking to Boost since I've been able to run the Hello World program that comes with every new project in Code::Blocks using the Terminal. I've searched and tried most of the Boost setup instructions on the Code::Blocks wiki and the Code::Blocks forums but they don't seem to be working. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Also, I am using Mac OS X 10.6.8

Comment: Check your library paths (conflicting versions of boost libs?) and the environment (specifically, locale options (try `LANG=C`). Also, `ldd ./ubuntu` could shed some light